# Copy paste information with matching IDs that has more than 100000 rows in each sheet within Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Hello Currently I have code that is able to run and do a match within 2 sheets and copy paste the information from "sheet 2" to "sheet 1" when both IDs match.

However, I have more than 100000 rows on each sheet. Thus, when I run the code it keeps running. I tried the code for less than 1000 rows and it works after it runs for 3-4 Minutes. However when I tried to run for 100000 rows, it keeps running.

I hope someone can help me perhaps to improve my code to allow it to run for more than 100000 rows.  This is the code that I have:

```
Sub AAA()


  Dim tracker As Worksheet
    Dim master As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellFound As Range
    Dim OutPut As Integer

   Set tracker = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set master = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")


    For Each cell In master.Range("A2:A100000")

        Set cellFound = tracker.Range("A5:A43000").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then

            cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value2 = cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2

        Else

        End If
        Set cellFound = Nothing
        Debug.Print cell.Address
    Next
    OutPut = MsgBox("Update over!", vbOKOnly, "Update Status")


End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!:)

Comment: You need to take time to read and understand the answer to your previous question whichh address pretty much exactly the same issue.  It provides an answer using VBA dictionaries that could be adapted to do what you want.  I think you would be best off using the query solution I suggested below though. Your other question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470855/run-through-a-loop-for-more-than-100-000-rows-of-data-in-two-sheets-in-the-same/32472168#comment52844327_32472168

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub compare_sheet1_with_sheet2()  
For i = 1 To 100000
For j = 1 To 100000

If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & j).Value Then


Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
  .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

End If
Next j
Next i
end sub
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the code you gave but it does not run at all when i run it @AshwithUllal

Comment: When i press run, the code does not run at all @AshwithUllal

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Optimize VBA:

- ScreenUpdating = False
- Turn off AutomaticUpdating
- etc.

See more tips [here](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/).

### Option 2: MS Query

How bout a quick MS Query?:

```
SELECT S1.COLUMN_A, Iif(S2.COLUMN_A IS NULL, S1.COLUMN_B, S2.COLUMN_C) FROM
[Sheet1$] as S1 LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] as S2 ON S1.COLUMN_A = S2.COLUMN_A
```

Replace the `COLUMN_X` with the right column headers.

Feel free to use my [SQL AddIn](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/) or go to Excel and select <kbd>DATA</kbd>-><kbd>From Other Sources</kbd>-><kbd>From Microsoft Query</kbd>

Comment: Interesting idea: what's the VBA code to get the above query into a cell or range? Do you generate a query table for that? What kind of SQL syntax is supported by MS Queries? It doesn't seem to be ANSI standard with `Iif` in the syntax.

Comment: It's an OleDB query (MS Access type SQL) - supported across all MS Office applications. To generate the VBA just click `Record Macro` and create a MS Query as I mentioned above. This will generate the VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The AnalystCave.com addin mentioned is essentially a wizard to create Querytables, which are a standard excel feature.  Once created the QueryTable is saved with the workbook and the addin is no longer needed.

Excel also provides the user a way to create these QueryTables (without using VBA) but the process is horrible.

Having just used the addin, I would recommend using it, and recommend not writing your own VBA code to create the QueryTable for yourself (as it's time consuming).  However if you do want to create them using VBA here is some code to start you off.

Note that an alternative is to use MS PowerQuery, but for simple stuff the addin is much easier and quicker than power query (well done Microsoft, but the addin author wins this round)

```
Sub CreateAQueryConnection()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim MyConnection  As String
Dim qt As QueryTable


Set wks = ActiveSheet

'Clear worksheet of old QueryTables
For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
    qt.Delete
Next qt

' Build a connection string using http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/
' (The one below is overkill!)

MyConnection = Join(Array( _
"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\Harvey\OneDrive\My Study\Excel Study\SQL Addin1.xlsx;Mode=S" _
, "hare Deny Write;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:E" _
, "ngine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLE" _
, "DB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale " _
, "on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLE" _
, "DB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False" _
), "")

'Check if querytable exists
If wks.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then
    Set qt = wks.QueryTables("qt" & wks.codename)
Else

    Set qt = wks.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=MyConnection, Destination:=wks.Cells(1, 1))

End If

With qt


    .CommandType = xlCmdSql

    ' Yuo will need to chnage the sql that you use
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT T1.* FROM [Sheet1$] AS T1")


    ' you could set the name here - it's done already
    ' .Name = ""

    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = True
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False

    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True

    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .RefreshPeriod = 60

    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

' Set ExecuteSQL = qt.ResultRange
Debug.Print qt.ResultRange.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i am not encourage to use any SQL because my supervisor would prefer a macro VBA coding or excel functions to be used instead @HarveyFrench

Comment: I would try using SQL, show it to your supervisor and see what he says!